# How to build Julia on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, build, compilation, julia

[Julia compilation instructions](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia#source-download-and-compilation) links to [a list of required libraries](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia#Required-Build-Tools-External-Libraries) which looks rather daunting.

However, I was able to get away with:

```
brew install gcc      # took ~4h on my 2011 MacBook Air
brew install cmake
make                  # took another ~3h
```

My OSX is a fresh install, although I do have XCode installed.

I didn't need any of the [OSX installation instructions](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia#os-x) and I wonder if it would make sense to add the above instructions to that section.

I'm kind of answering my own question in the question –- someone (maybe me) can move it into an answer if it stands, and I can revise the question.

Comment: Julia downloads or ships with several of those libraries already. Xcode developer tools should suffice for building Julia from source. is there a problem with using the precompiled OSX installer?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you install Xcode, which gives you a lot of developer tools to build binaries.

Sometimes it gives me errors when I build Julia in OS X in parallel.

What I do instead is use the [precompiled package for OS X](https://s3.amazonaws.com/julialang/bin/osx/x64/0.5/julia-0.5.0-osx10.7+.dmg) and then make a soft link of the executable to your folder `/usr/local/bin/` in order to run Julia in terminal:

```
ln -s /Applications/Julia-X.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
```

where `X` is the version you installed.